# How could a question be marked duplicate in 2 minutes?

Tags: support, duplicates, closed-questions

I saw [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98454/haircut-in-an-imaginary-town) question. 2 minutes later, it was marked as a duplicate. How is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was spotted very soon after posting by a [riddle expert](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino) with a 'dupehammer'; their gold tag badge lets them singlehandedly close a question as a duplicate of another one. You can see this when you hover over the badge:

[image]

More information about this feature can be found on Meta Stack Exchange: [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/295232). The idea is that users who have solved so many [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle)s are likely to recognize when one is reposted.

Comment: Ironically, that question is not actually a [tag:riddle] and shouldn't have been tagged as such. It *is* a duplicate, though, so no harm done.